# am developing API in java so i need to handle exceptions my customException class extends which class either Exception or Runtime Exception

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions

my class extends which class please give me suggestion

```html
public class MyException extends Exception {

    public MyException (Exception ex) {
        super(ex);
    }

    public MyException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public MyException (Exception ex,String moduleKey) {
        super(ex, moduleKey);
    }

     public MyException (Exception ex, String moduleKey, String message) {
        super(ex, moduleKey, message);
    }
```

!-- end snippet -->

Comment: Are you asking or telling?

Comment: actually i am facing little bit confusion so am asking which class exxtends my custom class

Comment: Means you are asking which you super class you have to extend for your customException class right?

Comment: Me too have the same problem.. aactually in same confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on whether you want to force API users to try/catch (or declare throws) every time your exception *might* be raised, or you want them to crash the application just like NullPointerException does.

The first kind should be used whenever the exception is to be expected - like IOExceptions for instance. RuntimeExceptions usually suggest that something weird happend during (as the name suggests) runtime - a weird language behaviour, unexpected thread clash and so on. Usually you want to use the regular Exception though.

Comment: then what happen if i use throwable as my super class exception

Comment: k please explain some example Marandil

Comment: @ChanduD Imagine two different of exceptions:
1. InvalidPasswordException thrown, when you try to access a resource, but the password provided to access it was actually wrong. You don't want this to crash the application, you want to force the programmer to properly handle the exception whenever a method that can throw it is called (e.g. whenever password is input)
2. IndexOutOfBounds thrown by a list implementation. Forcing the programmer catch that error every time he uses get accessor, he would either declare throws everywhere or just try/catch whole functions defying the purpose.